# How to use multiple random in single mcq quiz app for android

Tags: android, random

In a single quiz how to use multiple random questions. for example 10 questions randomly selected from one category another 10 questions randomly selected from another category.

Comment: If available please Post a link for sample app or source code like my needed app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need 3 lists of Question (POJO class contains question,answer,category ...)

```
List<Question> physicsList  //fill the list
List<Question> chemistryList 
List<Question> biologyList

private String chooseRandomPhysicsQuestion(){
Random rand=new Random();
int randomIndex=rand.nextInt(30);  // random int from 0 : 30
return physics.get(randomIndex).getQuestion() ; //use it inside TexView for example
}
```

the same goes for other lists

Comment: If any android app available in same or source code please give me a link

Comment: I don't think it will be hard for you. search and get your hand dirty, you will learn too much along the way,good luck